# Can I safely delete import folder after sync to Adobe Cloud?

Tags: lightroom

I imported images into Lightroom CC on my MacBook Air. I now have a 20GB folder under `library.lrlibrary/` called `d3cb...many more letters.../`. I'd like to recover the space on the laptop. Lightroom says that I'm fully synced. Can I safely delete the `d3cb...` folder? Should I do it, somehow, inside of Lightroom or just delete it with the OS?

Comment: I'd double-check Adobe's meaning of 'sync'… because sync is *not* backup. I don't use Adobe's online services at all, but such as Apple's iCloud & DropBox sync means if you delete an item from one machine, it will 'helpfully' delete it from all your others.

Comment: Hi Larry! If you search the web for "lightroom delete synced photos locally" (or some other variation) there are plenty of (outdated?) methods to be found on-line. Have you looked into any of them? If so, could you please edit your question to include what you've found so far? This would prevent someone from suggesting something that you've looked into already but found unhelpful.
Also, can you specify which version of Lightroom you're using (Classic or CC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest route seems to be to adjust Lightroom's "Local Storage" down to a minimal size. After syncing and a restart, the file is purged down to the size you specify.